# How to write unzip using foldr in scheme?

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, scheme, racket

This is the code for `unzip` function coded in Scheme

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (define (firsts lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (caar lst)
              (firsts (cdr lst)))))
  (define (seconds lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        '()
        (cons (cdar lst)
              (seconds (cdr lst)))))
  (list (firsts lst) (seconds lst)))
```

will give us output like this:

```
(unzip '((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6))) => '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))'
```

But I'm curious that how could I implement the same function `unzip` using Scheme `foldr` function, anyone could help ? Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to mention the language you have programmed?

Comment: I used Scheme to program in this case

Answer (score 1):

Since you used the `racket` tag, I'll give an answer using [`for/fold`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html?q=for%2Ffold#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._for%2Ffold%29%29), which has much nicer syntax than `foldr` or `foldl`.<sup>1</sup>

The syntax for `for/fold` is roughly:

```
(for/fold <accumulators>
          <iterators>
  <body>)
```

We can use two accumulators `ret1` and `ret2` to store each of the two lists, and then put them together in the accumulators `#:result` form:

```
([ret1 '()]
 [ret2 '()]
 #:result (list (reverse ret1) (reverse ret2)))
```

The iterators are fairly straightforward:

```
 ([i (in-list lst)])
```

And finally, the body just needs to break apart each pair, and append it to the accumulator:

```
(values (cons (car i) ret1)
        (cons (cdr i) ret2))
```

So putting it all together gives:

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (for/fold ([ret1 '()]
             [ret2 '()]
             #:result (list (reverse ret1) (reverse ret2)))
            ([i (in-list lst)])
    (values (cons (car i) ret1)
            (cons (cdr i) ret2))))
```

As expected:

```
> (unzip '((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6))) 
'((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

<sub><sup>1</sup>At least in my opinion, these things are always a bit subjective.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

**Most beautiful solution - but without `foldr/l`**

```
(define (unzip al) (list (map car al) (map cdr al)))
```

**Solution 1 - with `foldr`**

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (foldr (lambda (next-pair acc) (list (cons (car next-pair)
                                             (car acc))
                                       (cons (cdr next-pair) 
                                             (cadr acc))))
         '(() ())
         lst))
```

Note: In `foldr` - although not intuitive - The second argument (and not the first) is the accumulated result (thus now renamed to `acc`) - which is the first and second list in a final-result's list - and `p` is the next pair in the list. So the first in the result list is `(car acc)` and the second is `(cadr acc)`. I misunderstood it myself before - by naming the arguments of the `lambda` function `p1` and `p2` thinking that `foldr` acts on the first and last pair of the `lst`. So by solving your question I gained some better understanding of what the two arguments in the inner `lambda` function of of `foldr` actually mean - one is the accumulated result and the other is the next element in the input-list. However, now tried `foldl`: The inner `lambda`'s arguments are in the same order like in `foldr` - first the next-pair and then the accumulated result.

**A solution with `foldl`**

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (foldl (lambda (p acc) (list (append (car acc) (list (car p)))
                               (append (cadr acc) (list (cdr p)))))
         '(() ())
         lst))
```

**An slightly more efficient `foldl` solution**

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (let ((res (foldl (lambda (p acc) (list (cons (car p) (car acc))
                                          (cons (cdr p) (cadr acc))))
                    '(() ())
                    lst)))
    (map reverse res)))
```

Instead of `append`, `cons`sing the result and at the end `reverse`ing the resulting inner lists.

**Solution 2 - with `foldr`**

Not efficient, but helped to get to solution 1 `(flatten (list x y))` -> `(cons x y)`:

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (foldr (lambda (next acc) (list (flatten (list (car next)
                                              (car acc)))
                               (flatten (list (cdr next) 
                                              (cdr acc)))))
         '(() ())
         lst))
```

**Solution 3 - with `foldr`**

Even more unefficient - but helped to get to solution 2 `(append (list x) (list y))` -> `(list x y)`:

```
(define (unzip lst)
  (foldr (lambda (next acc) (list (flatten (append (list (car next)) 
                                                (list (car acc))))
                               (flatten (append (list (cdr next)
                                                      (cdr acc))))))
         '(() ())
         lst))
```

**A tail-recursive solution without `foldr/l`**

```
(define (unzip alist)    
    (define (.unzip l acc) ; even numbered l as a given
      (cond ((null? l) (map reverse acc)) ; reverse both inner lists
            (else (.unzip (cddr l) (list (cons (car l) (car acc))
                                         (cons (cadr l) (cadr acc)))))))
    (.unzip (flatten alist) '(() ())))
```

All give:

```
> (unzip '((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6))) 
'((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple implementation doesn't use `fold`*, `map`, `reverse`, `flatten`, or `append` - and it uses a tail call

```
(define (unzip xs (return list))
  (if (empty? xs)
      (return empty empty)
      (unzip (cdr xs)
             (lambda (l r)
               (return (cons (caar xs) l)
                       (cons (cdar xs) r))))))

(unzip '((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6)))
;; '((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

Comment: This is elegant, though I suspect the cost of allocating a closure for each iteration may not turn out to be an improvement over either intermediate lists and `reverse` or building context through a non-tail call.

Answer (score 0):

Building on Leif's answer, Racket has more forms like `for/fold` that handle some parts of accumulation for you. For example:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (unzip lst)
  (for/lists (firsts seconds #:result (list firsts seconds))
             ([pr (in-list lst)])
    (values (car pr) (cdr pr))))

(unzip '((1 . 2) (3 . 4) (5 . 6)))
```